# Trying to run cygwin64 inside anaconda, can't get Tee command to run

Tags: cygwin, tee

I need to run a script (already given to me) called run_softmax.sh that runs some commands (including 'python') on my windows 10 machine. I have anaconda and cygwin64 installed. Inside anaconda, I first activate my python environment. Then I tried running `C:\cygwin64\bin\bash run_softmax.sh` but it gives me `run_softmax.sh: line 13: tee: command not found`

How can I add this functionality to cygwin?